# Setting up a development environment to learn PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to setup a sandbox environment to hone in on my pl/sql and database skills.  I was thinking of downloading the full version of Oracle 11G and using SQL Developer.  Setting up a test database and working from there.

Any recommendations?  Do you think this is a good approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL Developer is fine. If you've got spare cash, TOAD is also very good

Comment: Thanks for recommending TOAD.  I would like to setup a completely free env to start.  Is there any functionality that TOAD offers that should make me spend the money though?  From what i understand you can accomplish anything with SQL Developer that you can with TOAD.

Comment: Yes, TOAD was once the leading tool (I guess), but by now, SQL Dev is good enough so that you do not need other SQL and PL/SQL developer tool. I use SQL Dev since it was initially launched and never felt the need for anything else. On the other hand, I always found TOAD amateurish/non-professional looking (it is not! I admit; I just never liked to look and feel). But that's matter of taste.

Comment: I use Oracle's [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (a new major version was released just a week ago) to browse databases. I see no reason to use TOAD, but YMMV. For PL/SQL coding is use my favorite text editor and SQL*Plus from command line to install/compile the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to sandbox the whole environment, Oracle provide pre-built VM images which contain an 11g database, SQL Developer and other tools; more info [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html), and if you just want PL/SQL the [first version listed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) should have everything you need.

As well as being very quick and easy to set up - no DBA knowledge required - it's completely isolated from any real environments you want to avoid interfering with, can run on any machine and O/S that runs VirtualBox, and best of all, if (or when) you really mess something up you can trash it and start again.

Comment: Alex, i will give your suggestion a try this week!  I think it makes the most sense for what i am trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for Alex's comment, I use these all the time. I have used the 10g and 11g versions of the VM (usually it is prepared for Developer Days events) and it has been a great help.

Comment: Using Windows XP, Q 720 @ 1.60 GHZ, 3.0 GB Ram.  The VM runs slow using its default configuration.  Other than that so far its working great, however debating on installing Oracle 11G + SQL Developer outside the VM because of the performance issue.

Comment: Hey guys, i wrote a walk-through of my env after taking your advice:  http://devhub.fm/setting-up-an-oracle-11g-sandbox-dev-environment/

Comment: @Mo - thanks, useful write-up, it pulls together a couple of things I used to get started. (Noticed a typo - 'lunch' instead of 'launch'). Not surprised you're struggling a bit with performance, that is the downside of any VM. On the other hand, if you get a new machine, or even find one you can dedicate to this, you can just move the VM images without having to rebuild anything else. Good luck with your skill-honing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is perfectly good. Download latest 11g and SQL Dev. Read [Steven Feuerstein](http://www.stevenfeuerstein.com/books) books. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

ISTBC, but I believe you need a licence to run 11g Enterprise Edition, Standard Edition or Standard Edition One.

Express Edition however is free.  It's exactly the same database, it just has some size limits that you're unlikely to hit whilst you're learning.

> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an
>   entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database 11g
>   Release 2 code base.  It's free to develop, deploy, and distribute;
>   fast to download; and simple to administer.

More info here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html

Comment: For development and testing purposes you can run the enterprise version. See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html "*to use the programs only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your application*"