# how to create a local offline sqlplus database from an sql file?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm in a database class and the teacher wants us to connect through ssh to an oracle database setup on a school server and it's been extremely frustrating. She wants us to turn in an sql file that will create all the necessary table, insert tuples, run certain select commands which I've found to be very hard to get an sql file with everything after i get everything right and I haven't found a way to test the sql file against the server and I don't think I have permission to drop tables anyway. Anyway my question is there a way I can take an sql file with create table and insert commands to convert it to something like an access .mba database or something local i can mess around with? and help would be greatly appreciated didn't find much help on google.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing terminology a bit; SQL*Plus is a client application, and the database is a shared server resource. You want to create schema objects from an SQL file, I think. But anyway...

There's a very useful online resource for experimenting with bits of SQL in various flavours, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Technically not 'offline' of course, but I'm taking that to mean off your school's network, not necessarily completely isolated. You can create tables and run your inserts in the schema panel, and then run queries against that. Make sure you pick the right database product from the drop-down menu so you're using syntax that is valid for your class. You'll see a lot of answers here with links to demonstration fiddles.

That's great for a lot of things but if you want something a bit more robust and scalable, and entirely offline, you can install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and get a [pre-built developer VM image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) which gives you a ready-to-go Linux environment with a database installed and running. You can run whatever you want against that, you have SQL*Plus and SQL Developer available, and you can connect to the DB from your host machine if you want to. You can create and test your scripts against that, and in a format that will be closer to what you have to hand in than you'd use with SQL Fiddle.

This is much less work than installing the Oracle software yourself and learning how to create and manage the database, which I'm guessing is a bit more advanced than you need at the moment, based purely on the kinds of thing your question suggests you're dong at the moment. I think you'd learn a lot from the installation and build process, but I'd get comfortable with Oracle first, and maybe practice in a VM first as it's so much easier to trash it and start again when you mess something up.

If I wanted 'something local I can mess around with', I would go for a VM image. [Mo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139203/mo) posted a [walkthrough of the VM setup](http://devhub.fm/setting-up-an-oracle-11g-sandbox-dev-environment/) as a comment to a previous [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289802/266304), which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"Something local I can mess around with" in terms of Oracle Database is Oracle Database 11g Express Edition. It's free and can be downloaded from [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen). You certainly can test sql-files run through sqlplus on Oracle Database XE.
To get the MS Access (GUI) feeling, download SQL Developer. It's free.

Best of luck!

Bjarte