# I want to use SQL*Plus on my Mac, but I can't establish a connection

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I can't connect form SQL*Plus or SQL Developer; I [get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9yxP.png):

> Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Things I already installed:

- SQL Developer
- Java
- Oracle basic instant client
- Oracle SQL*Plus instant client

I put the last two into folder `instantclient_11_2`.

I could not find a solution for this anywhere online. A similar problem 
on Windows platform has been solved.

What are the next steps?

Comment: The things you say you've installed don't include the Oracle server software. But that isn't surprising as it isn't available on OS X any more. Do you have an existing database somewhere else you're trying to connect to?

Comment: nope. Not any other database. 
So, how to use sql plus on mac? I was using mysql earlier. I wanted to try this out.

Comment: Well you need a database to connect to. You've installed *client* software, not *server* software, so you don't have a database, so you can't connect. What are you actually trying to do? If you don't have a DB are you trying to learn about administration, or SQL, or what?

Comment: trying to learn sql. help  me out here with the required softwares on OS X.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32828925/266304).

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks. So, I should download the image file and use VM to learn, right?

Comment: That's the [simplest way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9288871/266304), and really the only way if you only have access to a Mac, yes.