# Developer sandboxes for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ssis

We are developing a large data migration from Oracle DB (12c) to another system with SSIS. The developers are using a production copy database but the problem is that, due to the complexity of the data transformation, we have to do things in stages by preprocessing data into intermediate helper tables which are then used further downstream. The problem is that all developers are using the same database and screw each other up by running things simultaneously. Does Oracle DB offer anything in terms of developer sandboxing? We could build a mechanism to handle this (e.g. have dev ID in the helper tables, then query views that map to the dev), but I'd much rather use built-in functionality. Could I use Oracle Multitenant for this?

Comment: [You can sandbox whole environments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289802/266304) but that might not be what you mean. Is there a reason developers can't have their own schemas to experiment in, rather than needing a whole separate database?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "experiment in". Using a production copy database is beneficial in that it contains real data. The downside is that it is way too large. Running a particular SSIS package may take 1-2 hours. Ideally we would have developer sandboxed sample databases that wouldn't contains as much data but would still contain real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up producing a master subset database of select schemas/tables through some fairly elaborate PL/SQL, then made several copies of this master schema so each dev has his/her own sandbox (as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole) suggested). We could have used [Oracle Data Masking and Subsetting](https://www.oracle.com/database/data-masking-subsetting/index.html) but it's too expensive. Another option for creating the subset database wouldn have been to use [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/). I should note that we didn't have a need to mask any sensitive data.

Note. I would think this a fairly common problem so if new tools and solutions arise, please post them here as answers.